# Jruby - TypeError: illegal access on 'clone'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.zlib.RubyZlib to field java.util.zip.CRC32.crc
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.zlib.RubyZlib
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
rails aborted!
TypeError: illegal access on 'clone': class org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod cannot access a member of class java.lang.Object (in module java.base) with modifiers "protected native"
```

I'm suddenly getting this error. Any help would be appreciated.

java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I presume you haven't seen this: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/4834

Comment: @mcfinnigan I have seen that but still confused where I should put the --add-opens flag. Also tried 
export JAVA_OPTS="$(echo --add-opens=java.base/{java.lang,java.security,java.util,java.security.cert,java.util.zip,java.lang.reflect,java.util.regex,java.net,java.io,java.lang}=ALL-UNNAMED) --illegal-access=warn" but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Hi I too faced the same problem with OpenJDK9.

```
# java --version
openjdk 9.0.4
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+12-Debian-4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+12-Debian-4, mixed mode)

# jruby -v
jruby 9.1.16.0 (2.3.3) 2018-02-21 8f3f95a OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 9.0.4+12-Debian-4 on 9.0.4+12-Debian-4 +jit [linux-x86_64]
```

and

```
activerecord-jdbc-adapter -v 1.3.24
```

I just gave the fix in gem level then it's not blocking me to proceed further. Just try this.
Go to the `driver.rb` in the following path:

> activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.3.24/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/driver.rb

Then edit the following line in the connection method

```
properties = self.properties.clone
```

Change this to:

```
properties = self.properties.dup
```